# Get Files or folder in Reverse order stored in SD Card in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to get folders and files in descending order from last to first. But i Don't want to get from lastmodify() method. Because in case I delete file from any folder. That folder data fetch firstly. This is my Model Class.

```
public class CallRecord implements Comparable<CallRecord>{

public String name;
public String time;
public String callType;
public String number;
public String filePath;
public String fileDuration;
public String folderName;
public String photoUri;
public boolean isStatic=false;


public String getPhotoUri() {
    return photoUri;
}

public void setPhotoUri(String photoUri) {
    this.photoUri = photoUri;
}

public String getFolderName() {
    return folderName;
}

public void setFolderName(String folderName) {
    this.folderName = folderName;
}

public boolean isStatic() {
    return isStatic;
}

public void setStatic(boolean aStatic) {
    isStatic = aStatic;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getCallType() {
    return callType;
}

public void setCallType(String callType) {
    this.callType = callType;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getFilePath() {
    return filePath;
}

public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
}

public String getFileDuration() {
    return fileDuration;
}

public void setFileDuration(String fileDuration) {
    this.fileDuration = fileDuration;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(CallRecord callRecord) {

    Long date1 = Long.valueOf(this.getTime().substring(1, 5));
    Long date2 = Long.valueOf(callRecord.getTime().substring(1, 5));
    return (date2>date1 ? -1 : (date2==date1 ? 0 : 1));
}
```

}

Comment: are you putting folder name into ArrayList?? if Yes then you can sort order. and then show into list.

Comment: @SachinShelar I am using List<Model> for store Folders and files into the list. Then i use Comparator class for compare file using lastmodified() method but it return me first that folder which is recently modified.

Comment: Then it is possible to sort order please provide your model class i will provide solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution to get Folders from last to first means in reverse order .
This code is work for me

```
 Arrays.sort(filesList, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File object1, File object2) {


                Date date=null,date1=null;
                String dateString=object1.getName();
                String dateString1=object2.getName();

                dateString=dateString.replace("-","/");

                dateString1=dateString1.replace("-","/");


                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                try {
                     date = sdf.parse(dateString);
                    date1=sdf.parse(dateString1);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Long dat =date.getTime();
                Long dat2 = date1.getTime();


                if (dat > dat2) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (dat < dat2) {
                    return +1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This How to Sort

// Here PhonebookContactModel is model class

// Sort Name ORDER Z - A

// Want to change sort Order, Change object in compare.

```
  Collections.sort(mArrayContactList, new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                PhonebookContactModel p1 = (PhonebookContactModel) o1;
                PhonebookContactModel p2 = (PhonebookContactModel) o2;
                return p2.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p1.getName());
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am store files in folder. Folder is create daily and its name is on today date like that  '2017-04-11'

Comment: did you try my solution??

Comment: yes, it gave this Exception:- Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int java.lang.String.count' on a null object reference